# Uniform convergence of Fourier series in terms of modulus of continuity

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

In the section Uniform Convergence in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series it is given the result of D. Jackson which states that if $f \in C^p$ is $2\pi$-periodic and $f^{(p)}$ has modulus of continuity $\omega$, then 
$$
|f(x) - (S_N f)(x)| \leq K \dfrac{\log N}{N^p}\omega(2\pi/N)
$$
for $K > 0$ a constant independent of $N,f,p$. Here $S_N f$ denotes the $N$-th partial sum of the Fourier series expansion of $f$. I have been unable to find the proof of this and was wondering if anyone would be kind enough to show it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess [this](http://books.google.ru/books?id=e6GPCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA21) is the page of Jackson’s book referenced by Wikipedia's article.